# How to do drag and drop?

Tags: javascript

Just a simple drag and drop that doesn't work !!!!!!

I used the drag and drop code from another stack overflow post.

I'm trying to make the file(s) go into the file input when they are dropped.

The other code is mostly stylistic/ or is for displaying the file name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dropContainer">
        Drag and drop a file
        <br>
        or
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" hidden="hidden" />
        <button id="fakeButton">Select a file</button>
        <span id="fileText">No file Selected</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        const dropContainer = document.getElementById("dropContainer");
        const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        const fakeButton = document.getElementById("fakeButton");
        const fileText = document.getElementById("fileText");
        fakeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            fileInput.click();
        });

        // dragover and dragenter events need to have 'preventDefault' called
        // in order for the 'drop' event to register. 
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets
        dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        };

        dropContainer.ondrop = function (evt) {
            // pretty simple -- but not for IE :(
            fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

            // If you want to use some of the dropped files
            const dT = new DataTransfer();
            dT.items.add(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]);
            dT.items.add(evt.dataTransfer.files[3]);
            fileInput.files = dT.files;

            evt.preventDefault();
        };

        fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
            if (fileInput.value) {
                fileText.innerHTML = fileInput.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
            } else {
                fileText.innerHTML = "no file selected";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. I tried running your code and it seems fine. What specific issue are you running into? The only thing that could raise some issue is that you expect 4 files but I think that was just a typo. Remove the line `dT.items.add(evt.dataTransfer.files[3]);` and it should be fine.

Comment: alright, thank you !

Comment: just to clarify the code should take the file in and display the name of the file in the file text, because it is selected by the file input

Comment: My apologies, didnt look that far. I have made my answer fixing that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the event listener on the file input does not fire when you assign the file in the drop event. `fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {`

Embedding that code instead in a function, you could call it instead at the end of the `ondrop` event to finalize the expected behavior.

```js
const dropContainer = document.getElementById("dropContainer");
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
const fakeButton = document.getElementById("fakeButton");
const fileText = document.getElementById("fileText");

function SetFileName() {
    if (fileInput.value) {
        fileText.innerHTML = fileInput.value.match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[1];
    } else {
        fileText.innerHTML = "no file selected";
    }
};

fakeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fileInput.click();
});

// dragover and dragenter events need to have 'preventDefault' called
// in order for the 'drop' event to register. 
// See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#droptargets
dropContainer.ondragover = dropContainer.ondragenter = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
};

dropContainer.ondrop = function(evt) {
    // pretty simple -- but not for IE :(
    fileInput.files = evt.dataTransfer.files;

    // If you want to use some of the dropped files
    const dT = new DataTransfer();
    dT.items.add(evt.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    fileInput.files = dT.files;

    SetFileName()
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dropContainer">
        Drag and drop a file
        <br>
        or
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" hidden="hidden" />
        <button id="fakeButton">Select a file</button>
        <span id="fileText">No file Selected</span>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```